# Generate and send pdf through Google Forms to my email address - doesn't send, debugging to no assitance

Tags: email, debugging, pdf, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to send myself a form-based report as a pdf. The problem is, I don't receive any emails. Debugging doesn't help much, since that only tells me which values are "undefined" (they are being defined the instant one fills out the form and triggers the email by clicking send; in theory). My coding experience stems from the days of TurboPascal and .bat-files, and I have lately realised I need to shape up. Trying to figure out Android, and this is a little experiment at work. But I had forgotten the lost feeling of "what now?"...

Here's the code:

```
// Samfunnsutvikling kursrapport

var docTemplate = "TemplateIDinGoogleDoks";
var docName = "Kursrapport";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
var email = "worker@work.no";
var namn = e.namedvalues.namn;
var arrangement = e.namedvalues.arrangement;
var dato = e.namedvalues.dato;
var referat = e.namedvalues.referat;

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+namn)
.getId();
// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keynamn', namn);
copyBody.replaceText('keyarrangement', arrangement);
copyBody.replaceText('keydato', dato);
copyBody.replaceText('keyreferat', referat);

// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF
var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

// Attach PDF and send the email
var subject = "Kursrapport";
var body = "Kursrapporten frå " + namn + "";
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

// Delete temp file
DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

The script/document is authorized to send emails, but, oddly, I had to authorize it twice. It is saved.

Comment: Ah, Turbo Pascal. Good times. you score highly for quoting that one :-)

Comment: Haha, thanks! Just realized HOW long ago that was, when I tried to remember an adequate command to reply with...and came up empty handed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can add **[Logger.log()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata)** to print variable values or just messages to see how far does it reach.

It looks as **attachments** parameter expects *Blob[]* [type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options), however you are passing just *Blob*. So, it should be:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: [pdf]});
```

You may also want to replace *DocsList* with *DriveApp* class as-is since the first one is depricated.

**Update**

It turned out also that **getActiveSection()** [was renamed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2013#april_2013) to **getBody()**.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I added the extra brackets and, subsequently, went from DocsList to DriveApp, but I still don't receive the mail I expect. Debugging still results in the same "undefined"-values.

Comment: @Sjalabais did you check it can send without attachment?

Comment: 'code' GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body}); 'code'

Comment: I guess I'll just let this lie and create a .docx for people to fill in for themselves... :o

Comment: @Sjalabais ok, but did you check my update about getBody?